# InvalidDecimalScale SFMC CSV data import

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, csv, data-import

Anyone run into an InvalidDecimalScale error in the SFMC CSV data import?

I came up with a contrived example to test. I made my data extension super simple:
[image: Simple Data Extension]

It's a data extension with three fields. A number, a decimal and text field.
I'm uploading a very simple file:

```
Id,Hello,World
"89228","7.0","Bad"
"89229","0.00","Bad"
"89230","1","Good"
```

The third row uploads correctly. The first two do not. It looks like it's due to the values after the decimal point e.g. "7.0" or the "0.00"

The field is a decimal field? Why is there an error? Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT**: Error I'm getting in the text file are:

```
Row Number  Error Number    Error Code  Error Details   Row Data
0   88340068    InvalidDecimalScale InvalidDecimalScale [89228][7.0][Bad]
1   88340069    InvalidDecimalScale InvalidDecimalScale [89229][0.00][Bad]
```

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: Updated the original post with the output of the log file...

Comment: give like this data type Decimal field  length 18 and 2 not like 18 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this  see this image you get some idea[image]

Comment: give length 18,2 not like 18,0  then import records

Comment: Thanks, I changed it from 18,0 to 18,2 and it worked